# ¿Por qué algunas respuestas tienen opacidad?

Tags: soporte, respuesta, votos-negativos, diseño

Hoy encontré una respuesta marcada como aceptada que tenía varios votos negativos y un comentario que expresaba que no era una solución óptima al problema del OP.

Pasados unos minutos comencé a ver la respuesta con opacidad y al colocar el cursor del mouse sobre ella retomaba su color normal.

¿Qué significa que la respuesta esté con opacidad? ¿Era por la cantidad de votos negativos?

Comment: exacto, es por eso mismo, cuando tiene muchos negativos se va aclarando...

Comment: Interesante planteamiento.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cuando una respuesta tiene una puntuación de -3 o menos, pasa a tener un fondo más diluido.

Esto no es progresivo, sino binario:

Las respuestas con:

- Puntuación > -3 tienen fondo normal.
- Puntuación <= -3 tienen fondo semi transparente. Además, estas respuestas [tienen los snippets deshabilitados](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0/270981#comment92448_270981).

Tiene su lógica: En Stack Overflow se quiere hacer emerger el buen conocimiento y *hundir* lo que no es bueno. Por tanto, *medio ahogarlo* con un fondo transparente es una manera visual de indicar que esa respuesta no está teniendo la confianza de la comunidad.

---

En el código fuente se ve claro, pues pasa de ser del tipo:

```html
<div id="answer-XXX" class="answer" ...>
```

... a lo siguiente:

```html
<div id="answer-XXX" class="answer downvoted-answer" ...>
```

Mirando el CSS, se observa que la parte de `downvoted-answer` apunta a algo así como:

```css
{opacity:.5;transition:opacity .5s}
```